# What does this GitHub error message mean: "support for password authentication was removed"?

Tags: github

What I have to do to resolve this problem?

Comment: There is no screenshot, but it is much better to copy and paste the text anyway.

Comment: Seems like this is more a question about the inner workings of Github than related to Ubuntu... 

Answer (score 2):

The GitHub error message "support for password authentication was removed" means that GitHub removed support for password authentication.

What you do about it is one of two things: [create a personal access token](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token) or [enable ssh](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account).

For what it's worth, I chose ssh. I think it's the more secure of the two, and it's easier to use.